# Split a mathematical function containing using signs in java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I want to split a *mathematical function* by the sign of the variables in it like this :

```
 input-->   x-5y+3z=10

 output--> [x,-5y,+3z,=10]
```

this code does not work in the way i want :

```
String function = "x-5y+3z=10";
String split = function.split("=|-|\\+");
```

the output of the array is :

```
[x,5y,3z,10]
```

so what is the correct regex for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" using `split` is that the delimiter used will be removed, because it'll takt the parts that are between this delimiter, you need a pattern that is non-capturing or with a simple lookahead : match something wich is before something else

The pattern `(?=[-+=])` would work, it'll take the part that starts with a `-+=` symbol without removing it :

```
String function = "x-5y+3z=10";
String[] split = function.split("(?=[-+=])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split)); //[x, -5y, +3z, =10]
```

[*Some doc on Lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)